# Subtract data table by a subset of the data

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I hope it's not a duplicate, but I searched hard and didn't find the answer.

So, I have a big data.table (>50000 observations), here's the head:

```
   measure condition subject channel     score
1:     LZs      dark      03       1 0.5589379
2:     LZs      dark      03       2 0.5225509
3:     LZs      dark      03       3 0.5988951
4:     LZs      dark      03       4 0.5475331
5:     LZs      dark      03       5 0.5468930
6:     LZs      dark      03       6 0.5431141
```

I want to create a new column such as

`data$diff = data$score - data$score[data$condition%in%"dark"]`

I have 9 different measures, 5 conditions, 18 subjects and 64 channels - thus I can't check line by line if I get the expected result. Still, with a random check in the data I found out it wasn't the case.

**How to be SURE that this simple operation is done using the score of the right measure, subject and channel each time?**

Of course, I could do several `for` loops, but that's not nice R code. I assume it could be done using `dplyr`, but I'm not familiar with it and a simple `mutate()` didn't work better.

Comment: Try `data[, Diff := score - score[condition =="dark"], .(measure, subject)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we need to get the difference for each 'measure' and 'subject', specify the 'measure' and 'subject' in the `by` , subtract 'score' from those elements where 'condition' is 'dark' (the length is assumed to be same)

```
library(data.table)
data[, Diff := score - score[condition =="dark"], .(measure, subject)]
```

Comment: It seems to work, thanks a bunch! Could you explain why `:=` please? And I assume that `.()` is the same as `by=list()`?

Comment: @Heneark  You are right.  The `.()` or `list()` can be used.  The `:=` is assignment operatoro.  It assigns the value in place and is very efficient

Comment: Or `data[data[condition=="dark"], on=.(measure,subject), v := score - i.score ][]`